# How to get parameter from routing-url Google App Engine using Java JSP

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, url-routing

I write an App Engine Application using Java. I want to make my url look much better as URL Routing on ASP.NET. this is my Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/test.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I type http://localhost:8888/test/123 it work for me, And I use `request.getPathInfo()` to get value of *

it return `/123`, So I have to remove `/` by replace it to blank char. If I type http://localhost:8888/test/abc/123 it return /abc/123, but the value I want is only `abc`

Are there a better ways or pattern or library to solve this problem?

Comment: Use spring to build services - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service

Comment: I read about spring here , and I consider to do not use spring.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization

Answer (score 0):

> it return /123, So I have to remove / by replace it to blank char. If I type http://localhost:8888/test/abc/123 it return /abc/123, but the value I want is only abc

You could split the String to an array.